# Android - simple way to display installed apps, or tutorial?

Tags: android

Does anybody have a simple code to display a list (list view?) of all the apps installed on a phone, and have the user open one when clicked?

Or even an App drawer. I just need a way to have the user open all of their apps.

I have tried searching for tutorials, but couldn't find any, and I downloaded the example home from Android, but I absolutely hate looking through code and digging out what I Want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Home](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) sample application that comes with the SDK.

The basic idea is to use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get either

- a list of all installed packages using `getInstalledPackages` or
- a list of all launcher activities using `queryIntentActivities` for an intent with category `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` and action `ACTION_MAIN`

depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can get all the installed application.Write code to achieve additional requirement

```
  List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm;
        pm = getPackageManager();
                 get a list of installed apps.
                packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

       for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        //packageInfo.packageName is the name of the package


                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this code snippets posted here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon , you can have all the installed application.

Answer (score 0):

Rasel's Code worked ok for me.

Here is the full code: (
 would love to see some more comments so I understand why it works!)

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        packages= pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        Log.v("Alert","package is "+packages);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            String tempinfo= packageInfo.packageName;
            Log.v("Alert","this is working"+ tempinfo);
```