# How to list all Android application activities?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-package-managers

I'm building an android application and I want to list all activities of installed applications in format of com.pkg.name/com.pkg.name.activity. so far I have managed to list the app name, icon and package name. But im stucked with activity names. My full list should be like below.

====================

### App Icon - App name

## com.pkg.name/com.pkg.name.activity

Somebody please help. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your issue to describe your attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You can simply find an answer in another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904698/android-how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-activities-as-they-appear-in-launcher)