# Is it possible to open Android Wear Start Screen / Menu from an app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to open Android Wear Start Screen (the one with red G icon and text 'Speak Now') from my app. Is this possible?

thanks.
w

Comment: Do you _really_ need this particular screen or do you just want to add voice control/recognition ?

Comment: @Snow I would actually like to open that particular screen if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to launch this exact screen (no API for that).

However you can easily recreate a similar screen yourself.

This code lists the activities available in the launcher:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
//using hashset so that there will be no duplicate packages, 
//if no duplicate packages then there will be no duplicate apps
HashSet<String> packageNames = new HashSet<String>(0);
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfos = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>(0);

//getting package names and adding them to the hashset
for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfos) {
    packageNames.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
}

//now we have unique packages in the hashset, so get their application infos
//and add them to the arraylist
for(String packageName : packageNames) {
    try {
        appInfos.add(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        //Do Nothing
    }
}

//to sort the list of apps by their names
Collections.sort(appInfos, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
```

Then show the elements in `appInfos` into a [WearableListView](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html).

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351610/540990