# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual memory

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I receive this error when i attempt to run my app i think my menubutton is causing this error but dont really know how to fix the issue

**mainactivity**

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.List;

/*
This app is for a local Vape Shop
 it's purpose is to increase customer flow, and provide a menu for Android users

 the array is going to be called = da_menu
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Intent java;

    //used this to get rid of red line under intent on line 38 if it causes more problems remove and resolve issue
    private Intent intent;

    /*
    called when the user clicks the send Button
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
        attempting to send user to each individual app with the URI Intent method
         */
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List activites = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activites.size() > 0;

        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:9259619029");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/eastbayvapes");
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

        /*this is to send the user to facebook application

        try {

            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/eastbay"));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/eastbay"));

        }
        */


        // intent to send user to instagram

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/eastbayvapes");
        Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        try {
            startActivity(likeIng);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eastbayvapes")));
        }

        //Intent to send user to email app

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"eastbayvapes@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

        /*Intent to send user to google maps

        String uri = "https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=" + 1549 N Vasco Rd, Livermore, Ca 94551;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        context.startActivity(intent);
        */



        /*
        sends user to about us xml via AboutActivity.class
         */
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });




    }


}
```

**SecondActivity**
*Here i believe i am getting the cause of my error when i declared the menubutton but dont know what i did wrong*

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by vitoriano-vaz on 5/11/16.
 */
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menuscreen);

        /*
        this is the button call that sends user to the menuscreen.xml
         */
        Button mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menubutton);
        mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                populateListView();
            }
        });

        populateListView();

    }
    private void populateListView() {
        // Create the list of items

        String[] juiceMenu= {
                "#1 BLUEBERRY BOMBSHELL \nThis blueberry dessert will keep your taste buds begging for more",
                "#2 RICHIE RICH\nShout out to Rich! This was his all day vape. Strawberry cream with a bunch of deliciousness",
                "#3 CHIQUITA\nCreamy Banana with a bready after taste",
                "#4 AFTERNOON DELIGHT\nGot that 3 o'clock feeling? Try a little Afternoon delight. Kiwi Strawberry Dessert",
                "#5 POPPIN OTTERS\nMelt an otterpop put it in your tank and vape it",
                "#6 VIVA LA SANGRIA\nFruit, with a little bit of fruit,  add a teaspoon of fruit mixed with white win and top it off with fruit",
                "#7 OKOLE MALUNA\nPineapple fruit blend. Bottom up!",
                "#8 CARMEN MIRANDA\nVanilla custard with a crisp",
                "#9 POMALADE\nIt's Bombalade! Yuour mother will love it",
                "#10 IZUAL\nWhirlwind of icy Fruits",
                "#11 BUTTER STOTCH\nProfessor Chaos will surely get grounded for this one!",
                "#12 BLUE BULLS\nGrab the bull by the horns",
                "#13 GRAPE APE\nA grapple a day will keep the doctor away",
                "#14 BRUCE JUICE\nPerfectly blended old fashioned. This one is for you Bruce",
                "#15 DOC HOLIDAY\nN.E.T. Tabacco flavor. Limited release",
                "#16 PEACHY KEEN\nPeach cobbler. Better than what your mama used to make",
                "#17 HULA\nStrawberry coconut? What in the hula?",
                "#18 NEW YORK\nPeppermint paddy dipped in chocolate...Amazing really",
                "#19 AL GORE\nIm super duper cereal right now!",
                "#20 LUX CHARMS\nHearts, stars, horseshoes, clovers & blue moons, pots of gold % rainbows & me red balloons",
                "#21 SAILOR JACK\nCant go to the ball game without some cracker jacks",
                "#22 GET HIM TO THE GREEK\n...Yogurt, peach, delightful",
                "#23 KEY WE LIE CHI\nFruit lovers will enjoy this lychee vape",
                "#24 SPRING FLING\nA menage a trois of honeydew and cream on your tongue",
                "#25 GUMBY\nWatermelon sour gummy",
                "#26 CHAI\nMILK and Chai Tea",
                "#27 MR. BBEAN\nCappuccino with cream to start the day off right",
                "#28 50 SHADES OF ORANGE\nA delightful blend of orange and cream",
                "#29 BLUE WAFFLES\nBreakfast for dinner with this Blueberry Waffle",
                "#30 ENIGMA\nEnigma conundrum of mango raspberry with a hint of mystery can you solve the puzzle?",
                "#31 MR. FREEZE\nPut down the tank and STEP AWAY hardcore mint lovers ONLY! This juice is too coll for most",
                "#32 CUP OF JOE\nThe best part of waking up is coffee in your vape",
                "#33 BON JOVI\nVanilla Bourbon ",
        };
        // Build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,               // context for the activity
                R.layout.da_menu,   // Layout to create
                juiceMenu);         // Items to be displayed

        //configure list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:src="@drawable/ebvbottle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="East Bay Vapes"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FEFEFF"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:id="@+id/menubutton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="menubutton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="We are dedicated to helping people get off tabacco! We carry everything from beginner setups, to advanced personalized vaporizers. We pride ourselves in our premuim juices made in shop!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menuscreen**
**Here is where i want to send my populated array**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollIndicators="right">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my error**

`05-18 16:00:44.619 11983-11983/com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes, PID: 11983
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes/com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(android.content.ContentResolver)' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(android.content.ContentResolver)' on a null object reference
                                                                                            at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:808)
                                                                                            at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:797)
                                                                                            at com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6584)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:770) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your intent to make it not Null.

```
 List activites = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

**EDIT**

Remove the following part from your code as it has no use in the rest of your code. And never use them until you realize the reason why you need them.

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List activites = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activites.size() > 0;
```

Comment: How would i make it not NULL?

Comment: you should tell pakagemanager to find an activity which has some specific intentfilter like "android.intent.action.MAIN" or whatever you want and init your intent with new Intent("put your intent filter here"). Then use it. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9905443/5923606

Comment: So i tried the final example
when i typed appList.add(app) i get a error saying cannot resolve appList

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems you are totally lost as you are asking very basic things.